# Cannot initiate git repo on network share

Tags: git

I want to initiate a git repository on a network share. This produces the following error:

```
[path]: Invalid argument
```

It does not matter if I am in the directory, or if I use

```
git init [path]
```

Searching for git init errors did not give me anything useful. Any ideas where the problem might be?

I use Windows 7.

Comment: I assume `git init` works in a different directory, which is not a network share?

Comment: Yes, `git init` works otherwise. Actually it even does work on other network shares, just not on this one.

Comment: Can you show how you specify `[path]`?

Comment: like this: `git init X:/R_pkg_dev/classifier`

Comment: The error message then is: `X:/R_pkg_dev/classifier/.git: Invalid argument`

Comment: I assume you are using a windows os because of the X:/, have you tried using backslashes (`git init X:\R_pkg_dev\classifier`)?

Comment: Yes I am on Windows. Yes I did use backslashes. I don't think this is the issue (but I may be wrong), because the error also occurs when I `cd` into the directory, and because `git init` works on other network shares. Git just returns the path with forward slashes. Btw, Windows understands forward slashes - try it in the Windows explorer.